# NextJS: How to check if the current URL is the home page?

Tags: javascript, next.js

New to NextJS.

I want to check if the current URL is the home page.

If I use

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

const router = useRouter();
const is_home = (router.pathname === '');
```

I get a front end error

`You have a Server Component that imports next/router. Use next/navigation instead.`

If I change

`import { useRouter } from "next/router";`

to

`import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";`

I get a terminal error

`Error: useRouter only works in Client Components. Add the "use client" directive at the top of the file to use it.`

If I add `"use client"` to the top of the file, the terminal error goes away, but `pathname` in `router.pathname` is highlighted red in VS Code, and the hover error is

`Property 'pathname' does not exist on type 'AppRouterInstance'.ts(2339)..`

I can't find any documentation for `next/navigation` like there is for `next/router`.

Is there a simpler way to check for the home page?

I want to assign a default meta description for the home page, and assign the post excerpt (initally) as the meta description if the current URL is not the home page.

Comment: Hi Steve! Your question is very likely to be a duplicate of the linked thread. Let us know if it's not, and we will consider reopening it.

Answer (score 1):

If you try to use useRouter in a component that is being rendered on the server-side, you will get this error. To resolve this error, you need to **make sure** that the component is **only rendered on the client-side**.

One way to do this is by using the **dynamic import** function from next/dynamic to load the component asynchronously on the client-side.

```
    import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';

    const DynamicComponent = dynamic(() => import('../components/MyComponent'), {
      ssr: false, // set ssr to false to render only on the client-side
    });
```

and render it normally like you normally return jsx:

```
    return (   
          <DynamicComponent /> 
      );
```

OR if you want to render this component **on serverside use getServerSideProps** like this:

```
    export async function getServerSideProps(ctx) {
      const isHome = ctx.req.url === '/';

      return {
        props: {
          isHome
        }
      };
    }
```

and use the **isHome** prop like this:

```
  const HomePage = ({ isHome })=> (
    <>
      { isHome ? <h1>Welcome to the home page!</h1>: <h1>This is not the home page.</h1>}
    </>
  )

  export default HomePage;
```